# How to send data from PowerApp to Flow Automate (POST)?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I'm getting the error: 'Invalid argument type (Text). Expecting a Record value instead.' After using my Flow in my powerApp application.

**PowerApp**

```
'MyFlow-Save'.Run(
    "1234",
    "Some title", 
    "Some description",
    "Some code"
);
```

My flow (MyFlow-Save) works perfect, The insertion are presents on my DB. I'm just getting the error on powerApps. This is my flow (I've used "askInPowerApps" variables on my object here).

[image: PowerAutomate: MyFlow-Save]

Comment: that createdby maybe the culprit?

Comment: @ArunVinoth no :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the trigger action - click 3 dots and click peek code. From there you can see the inputs and their type. Please see the screen shot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain what I did to make this work.

1. Create the flow again from scratch.
2. I've added variables that are gonna considered in my request object (Post-Request).
3. I've initialize each of these variables with "askInPowerApps".
4. I've also consider important to name the variables on this block headers. (Because this is gonna help, later in Powerapps).
5. Finally I've added all of my variables into my Post-Request object.

I don't know if this could consider it as an answer because It's a variable thing that is kind of difficult to handle in flow automate, there is always variables being replicated that push you to create everything again from scratch.